# I am getting only first row of my table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am attempting, using a `while()` loop, to return all the data from a table called orders, and print them in an HTML Table.

I have tried 2 ways of looping through data.

1. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`
2. `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Both ways add only the first row to my HTML Table and just echo to the page any other rows.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>FORM SUCCESSFULLY SENT</h1>

<p>Here are the order details</p>

<?php
    $servername = xxxx;
    $username = xxxx;  
    $password = xxxx;  
    $databasename = xxxx;
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);           // Create connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);    // Check connection
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM orders";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);

?>
<table border="3" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 5 auto;" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Start City</th>
          <th>End City</th>
          <th>Tracking Number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          if (!$result) throw new Exception('Database error: ' . mysql_error());
          else
          {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_surname']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_start_city']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_end_city']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['order_tracking_number']."</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
                 echo "</table>";
              }
              $result->free();  // free result set
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<?php 
      $conn->close(); 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I get back

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 3 records. Remove:

```
echo "</table>";
```

from `while` loop, and it will work! :)

Comment: Have a nice day and happy coding! ;)

Comment: You too @Yupik ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your `echo "</table>";` need to be out of the `while` :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['client_surname']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['client_start_city']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['client_end_city']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['order_tracking_number']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Every Thing Is Fine !! Just `echo "</table>";`** Remove This From While Loop.

```
 <?php
          if (!$result) throw new Exception('Database error: ' . mysql_error());
          else
          {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_surname']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_start_city']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['client_end_city']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['order_tracking_number']."</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
                 //echo "</table>"; Remove This.
              }
              $result->free();  // free result set
          }
        ?>
```